# EH cache RMI replication not working

Tags: hibernate, caching, rmi, ehcache

I'm trying to setup EHcache replication using RMI over two tomcat servers. The setup is as following -

1. Two servers server1.com & server2.com
2. No firewalls blocking connections
3. An application testApp deployed on both the servers
4. Using hiberate query statistics to check hits/miss on caches

My ehcache.xml is configured as below for server1.com

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"
monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">


   <!-- Configure the default behavior of caches defined in this server -->
<defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="100" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="200">
</defaultCache>

<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=manual,rmiUrls=//server2.com:40001/testCache"/>

<!-- Configure a cache manager peer listener that listens for messages from peers -->
<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
        properties="hostName=solr2.souq.com, port=40001,socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>

<cache name="testCache" eternal="false" timeToIdleSeconds="100" 
timeToLiveSeconds="100" overflowToDisk="false">
<cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"
properties="replicateAsynchronously=true, replicatePuts=true, replicateUpdates=true,
replicateUpdatesViaCopy=false, replicateRemovals=true "/>
</cache>
```

For server2.com, the rmiUrl is the only modification

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory    class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
        properties="peerDiscovery=manual,rmiUrls=//server2.com:40001/testCache"/>
```

To test this arrangement,

1. I query for an entity on server1.com ( cache miss)
2. Querying again on server1.com for same entity gives cache hit.
3. Querying for this entity on server2.com gives a cache miss again ( it should hit the cache if replication has happened )

Please tell me what is going wrong here?

Comment: I guess for server 2 should be `rmiUrls=//server1.com:40001/testCache`. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution.. posting here in case anybody is floundering on the same iceberg -

I needed to instruct the entities to use testCache region I created. By default, all entities use the default cache region, unless explicitly mentioned by the 'cache-region' tag in hbm.xml files